# Php regular expression for preg_replace to remove a secific text

Tags: php, regex, arrays

I'm trying to remove a JS function from my JS functions array but I couldn't figure out the right regExp for it.

this is the text(function) I want to remove :

```
window.addEvent('domready', function() {

  SqueezeBox.initialize({});
  SqueezeBox.assign($$('a.modal'), {
    parse: 'rel'
  });
});
```

and I wrote this code for remove it:

```
<?php if (isset($this->functions['text/javascript'])) {
      $this->functions['text/javascript'] = preg_replace('%window\.addEvent\(\'domready\',\s*function\\(\\)\s*\\{SqueezeBox\\.initialize\\(\\{\\}\\);\s*SqueezeBox\\.assign\\(\\$\\$\\(\'a\\.modal\'\\), \\{parse: \'rel\'\\}\\);\\}\\);\s*%', '', $this->functions['text/javascript']);
      if(empty($this->functions['text/javascript'])) {
          unset($this->functions['text/javascript']);
      }
  } ?>
```

I'm not so good in regexp so I'm lost and don't know where look for error in the pattern.

Comment: You should match it more sparsely. Use `.*?` and just look for `SqueezeBox` within instead of asserting the whole function body. You forgot a `\s*` before `parse:` for instance. Might need more of those. (Good job on the escaping however.)

Comment: What if you remove preg_replace and just give "" ? - Sorry my question was pathetic.

Comment: One problem is that you need to use the [`s (PCRE_DOTALL)` flag](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php) if you want the `*` to match newlines.

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem I think you mean `s`. The `m (PCRE_MULTILINE)` flag only changes the behavior of the `^` start of line and `$` end of line metacharacters. See the link in my previous comment: "If there are ... no occurrences of `^` or `$` in a pattern, setting this modifier has no effect."

Comment: @user113215: Yup, I meant the `s` flag, comment removed

Comment: Thanks everyone for the help. I will trying to make this work but until then I think I will unset the whole array and after the unset I will set it back with the functions which are required.

Answer (score 0):

Regexes are poorly adapted to solving this sort of problem. I would recommend outputting some sort of flag variable from the php and using it as a condition in your js, which would go something like this:

```
window.addEvent('domready', function() {
if(flag){
  SqueezeBox.initialize({});
  SqueezeBox.assign($$('a.modal'), {
    parse: 'rel'
  });
}
});
```

You can then output `var flag=true` or `var flag = false` in your php, depending on your logic.

Comment: If you have that kind of control over the page (the ability to inject JavaScript into the page) you should just inject the script itself using PHP when it is needed, rather than outputting a JavaScript flag.

Comment: I suspect there is a js file being included, in which case you don't have the option of selectively outputting parts of it.

Comment: Thanks it's a good idea but @Asad is right I don't have the option of selective outputting.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I made it. Thanks to everyone for help!

This is final code which worked for me.

```
<?php 
  if (isset($this->functions['text/javascript'])) {
      $this->functions['text/javascript'] = preg_replace('%window\.addEvent\(\'domready\',\s*function\(\)\s*{\s*SqueezeBox.initialize\(\{\}\)\;\s*SqueezeBox.assign\(\$\$\(\'a.modal\'\)\,\s*{\s*parse:\s*\'rel\'\s*}\);\s*}\);\s*%', '', $this->functions['text/javascript']);
      if(empty($this->functions['text/javascript'])) {
          unset($this->functions['text/javascript']);
      }
  } 
?>
```